# How to get rid of the “Google Accounts” giant letter on Google sites?

Tags: google-accounts

Notice this big pink circle:

[image]

It’s distracting, and honestly kind of an eyesore. I’ve managed to get rid of it with uBlock in Gmail, but with Google Images, it just keeps coming back. Perhaps I need a special filter to be rid of it, but I’m not sure what that would be. What can I do to not see this anymore?

Answer (score 4):

Change your Google Account image or If you haven't set an account image so far, upload a new profile picture. Refer the following link:

https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1057172?hl=en